# Angular - Es posible recibir una invocacion POST, con body, desde el browser y resolverla con Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Esta consulta es mas que nada una consulta técnica...no hay mucho código para mostrar. Necesito resolver una invocación por POST, desde el browser y atraparla en Angular 7. Es decir...una programa externo, va a realizar un POST con body en el navegador con una url a mi crm hecho en angular 7.
Yo normalmente cuando me invocan una ruta en el browser con parametros normalmente vienen por GET, del siguiente estilo:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/page/mypage/{id}
```

o

```
http://localhost:4200/#/page/mypage?id=1&name="pepe"
```

Cualquiera de esas dos invocaciones, yo las puedo resolver con los Params del Router o con los QueryParams tambien del Router.
Ahora bien...en este caso me estan mandando por POST en el body, dado que necesitan que no se vean los parametros. Existe alguna forma de realizar este circuito?.

Comment: No acabo de entender el escenario: ¿un programa externo? ¿Cómo va un programa externo a hacer una llamada a través de tu aplicación?

Comment: Exacto. Un programa externo, va a hacer un POST a una url, esa url es justamente mi angular corriendo. Por ejemplo va invocar a http://localhost:4200/#pages/mypage y va a ir con parametros en el body. Entonces quiero saber si yo puedo resolver con el Router esa situacion

Comment: No puedes. Con Javascript solo podrias tomar valores GET teniendo en cuenta que tienes acceso a la URL. Javascript al ser un lenguaje del lado cliente no te permite obtener el cuerpo de una petición. Debes usar un lenguaje de servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a aclarar conceptos y estudiar el escenario:

1.- Un programa externo (asumo que una aplicación web corriendo en tu navegador) hace una petición HTTP con el método POST a tu servidor (backend).

2.- Tu servidor recibe la llamada POST y responde como lo tengas programado

Hasta este momento **no** se está pasando por una aplicación Angular, puesto que ésta debe cargarse en el navegador. Ahora...

La respuesta de tu servidor puede ser la página HTML que acaba cargando Angular en el navegador que inició la petición. Una vez que la aplicación se cargue en el navegador, el Router leerá la URL actual y cargará la vista que corresponda. **No** podrá acceder al cuerpo de la petición que originó la carga de la aplicación, porque **ya no existe**.

**Opciones**:

- El servidor, al responder, añade en el HTML donde reside tu aplicación información *extra* en un campo hidden o como un objeto Javascript:

  ```
  <html>
    ...
    <body>

    <script>
     const datosImportantes = {
       bodyRequest: ...
     };
    </script>
    ... <!-- Scripts y CSS de tu aplicación Angular -->
  </html>
  ```
- Tu aplicación hace una llamada nada más cargarse al servidor para conocer qué es lo que se ha enviado. Esto implica tener información en la URL que permita identificar la llamada anterior o tener una sesión abierta en el servidor, lo que chocaría con la idea de usar una API REST

Comment: A ver...por ahi no me expliqué bien. Si un programa, simula un click en un link y ese link es una url que coincide con mi app angular (por ejemplo: http://localhost:4200/#/pages/mypages?id=1&nama="pepe")...mi app angular resuelve y muestra lo que debe mostrar. Eso es asi porque yo lo he hecho. Entonces, existe un proveedor, que en su programa va a hacer lo mismo, solo que los parametros me los quiere pasar en el body...con lo cual es claramente un POST. La pregunta es, lo puedo resolver?

Comment: Es lo que he entendido y lo que te he respondido: Tu aplicación no podrá acceder al body de una request porque aún no está cargada. Pero en la respuesta podrías dar esa información a tu aplicación

Comment: Pablo, entiendo que no se puede porque la pagina aun no está cargada...no termino de entender las opciones que me das en tu respuesta. Te podrias explayar un poquito a ver si logro entenderlas para ver si me sirve o no. Gracias